# php object - function calls another function

Tags: php, function, object

I have a php object that is working fine. I'm now trying to get one public function to call a private one and I can't get it working...

```
  // Join - Headline & About Me
  public function updateHeadlineAboutMe($joinHeadline, $joinAboutMe) {

    // Profanity Audit Member Text
    $prof_headline = profanityAudit($joinHeadline);
    $prof_aboutme = profanityAudit($joinAboutMe);


    echo $prof_headline;
    echo $prof_aboutme;

   // other code here...    

}


  // Profanity Audit of Member Text
  private function profanityAudit($auditText) {
    return('ok');
  }
```

I'm just trying to get the private function to return a value so I know its being called successfully. This function will be used (by many functions) to compare text to a list of swear words in a table to see of the text needs manual reviewing...

What should I try to get this working?

thankyou very much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the functions are inside an object, you will need to use `$this`.

```
$prof_headline = $this->profanityAudit($joinHeadline);
```

Answer (score 1):

If both functions are in the same class, you missed $this.

```
$prof_headline = $this->profanityAudit($joinHeadline);
```

The other line as well.

If they are not in the same class, you won't be able to call a private function, because it is the idea of private functions: not to be called from outside.